# Reload page with javascript only one time for load cookies

Tags: javascript

I have a function that request a data for the user one time. I need reload the page after save these data in a cookie and server read these cookie, but i dont know if these cookie are defined or not. ¿How i reload only one time if i dont have a counter and dont like use parameter? the referrer dont change with reload.

I now have this methot, but i like change for remove parameters:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null
}

if (getURLParameter('reload') != 'true') {
  //here have function for load cookie
  window.location = window.location.href + '?reload=true';
}
```

Comment: Can you detail the overall goal you're trying to achieve ? For now it's seems to me that it's more like a design issue.

Comment: the problem are that these desing are force to me, imposed. The goal are get a parameter of these cookie give me in the finction that i have. These function are good and test, but i need reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol, which mean there is not way - within the protocol - to know the **state** of a request. For instance : is it the first time it's launched or the second time ?
Usual workarounds are adding a parameter to the request, as you suggests or using a cookie on the browser's side. This is how sessions are implemented in platforms like Java EE or PHP.

Why don't you test for another cookie like 'never been reloaded', if it does not exists : create this cookie and reload the page.

The tricky part is *when should you delete the cookie*, ie : when does your business logic wants you to reload the page again ? That's up to you to decide.